# как редиректить с сохранением метода?

Tags: nginx, http, post, redirect

Использую Rails с Puma + Nginx. в nginx установлены настройки редиректа с http на https (стандартные настройки letsencrypt), но при этом если на сервер пришел POST-запрос, редиректит с методом GET. из-за этого параметры из FormData пропадают. каким образом можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307

Comment: Но лучше задать себе вопрос «откуда вообще приходят запросы по http?» и постараться избавиться от таких запросов.